# How to run commands on a particular PC via Azure CI pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a PC (LB-1) connected to my company network (assume IP: 00.000.000.001).

My requirement: Anybody push/merge code to main branch I want to trigger my pipeline such that it runs cmd commands in one specific PC only (i.e. LB-1). This is because of certain hardware and software dependencies.

My company uses Azure DevOps for CI.

Below I have shared a starter pipeline code for reference:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

steps:

- script: |
    cd Downloads
    echo > sample.txt
    echo "Folder created successfully."
  displayName: 'Create Folder in Downloads'
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution out of many possibilities would be to connect to your specific host via SSH:

```yaml
steps:
- script: |
    ssh -t host "cd Downloads;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-on-target-machines-v3?view=azure-pipelines) task in your pipeline to run the commands on a particular machine.

For example:

```
- task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
  inputs:
    Machines: '00.000.000.001'
    UserName: 'your-username'
    UserPassword: 'your-password'
    InlineScript: 'New-Item -Path ''C:\Users\{username}\Downloads'' -Name "testfolder" -ItemType Directory'
    failOnStderr: true
```

Please note that this task uses **Windows Remote Management** (WinRM) to access on-premises physical computers or virtual computers that are domain-joined or workgroup-joined.

So, we need to set up **WinRM** for the target machine (your particular PC). To set up WinRM please see [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-on-target-machines-v3?view=azure-pipelines#prerequisites) for details.

For the machines part: (IP or FQDN)

> Provide a comma separated list of machine IP addresses or FQDNs along
> with ports. Port is defaulted based on the selected protocol. Eg:
> dbserver.fabrikam.com,dbserver_int.fabrikam.com:5986,192.168.12.34:5986
> Or provide build or release variables. Eg: $(variableName) If you are
> using HTTPS, name/IP of machine should match the CN in the
> certificate.

Comment: @Tester May I know if you have resolved the issue by above solutions? Just wants to check if I can do something for you.